# grep/awk/sed lines from match until text

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, lscpu

I would like to get the following output from `lscpu`:

```
(number of cores) x (cpu model name) @ (max mhz)
```

I already figured out the attribute I need:

- `Model name:`
- `Core(s) per socket`
- `CPU max MHz`

But on my system, there are multiple CPUs with different models and clock speeds. So I have multiple attributes in output named `Model name:`.

I want the output mentioned above, only with `grep`, `awk` and/or `sed`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you.

Comment: Never seen a system with CPUs of different models myself. Quite intriguing. Can you post the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `lscpu -J`?

Comment: Do you want the frequency of each core or the frequency as indicated in the CPU model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I want:

```
lscpu | grep -E "Model name:|Core\(s\) per socket:|CPU max MHz:" | awk "{printf(\"%s\n\", \$NF)}" | paste -d " " - - - | awk "{printf(\"%s x %s @ %.0fMHz\n\", \$2, \$1, \$3)}"
```